# Clojure: Check that predicate holds exactly once

Tags: clojure

Is there any function like `every?` or `some` in Clojure except it checks that the predicate holds exactly once?

For example:

```
(once? even? '(1 2 1)) => true
(once? even? '(2 2 1)) => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any function like that in `clojure.core` nor have I come across an existing library that advertises this.

Looking at the implementation of `some` in `clojure.core`, it uses `recur` but for `once?` you would need a mechanism to remember if you've seen a `true` value before. Making that internal value visible as a three-arity call, seems ugly. Also, I'd like to avoid traversing the collection completely if not necessary.

Hence, I'd go with reduce:

```
(defn once? [pred coll]
  (reduce 
    (fn once-reduce-fn [seen-true it]
      (if (pred it)
        (if seen-true 
          (reduced false)
          true)
        seen-true))
  false
  coll))

;; You can use this code under the Apache Software License 2.0 
;; in addition to StackOverflow defaults
```

It stops iterating the collection when it sees a second truthy result from the predicate and also works with empty collections or `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler:

```
(defn once?
  [f coll]
  (= 1 (count (filter boolean (map f coll)))))  ; or change `boolean` => `identity`
```

with result:

```
(once? even? [1 2 1]) => true
(once? even? [2 2 1]) => false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make one:

```
(defn once? [f xs]
            (= 1 (get (frequencies (map f xs)) true)))
```

Comment: `frequencies` builds a map, which you don't need. What about `(= 1 (count (filter f xs)))`?

Comment: Furthermore, `count` need not go beyond 2. Taking advantage of `filter`'s laziness, you can wrap it with `(take 2...)`, thereby avoiding marching through the rest of the collection pointlessly evaluating f:  `(defn once? [f xs] (= 1 (count (take 2 (filter f xs)))))`